# Is there any way to use input for a mathematical function?

Tags: python

My numerical analysis professor gave me a project on programming several numerical methods in python.
And he asked me to run the program for some given functions so he can see the results of the methods.
My question is :

Is there any way so we can code something which the user input any chosen function and see the wanted results?
Or we must define the wanted function in the program specifically and there isn’t any way to do so ?

Comment: You can always use `eval` (provided you trust the user).

Comment: In Python a function is an object. You can always build a list of dictionary of functions and call the relevant function knowing its index or key.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thankyou . Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class to store your functions and access it by function name using `getattr`:

```py
# Store your functions here
class Functions:
    def f(x):
        return x ** 2
        
    def dist(a, b):
        return pow(a**2 + b**2, .5)
        
    def g(x):
        return Functions.f(x) + 1
    
def main():
    while True:
        funcname = input('Insert the function name (type "exit" to stop): ')
        if funcname == 'exit':
            break
        
        # Checks if the function name exists in Functions
        if not hasattr(Functions, funcname):
            print('This function does not exist!')
            continue
        
        # Store the function in a variable
        func = getattr(Functions, funcname)
        
        # Ask the user for the arguments to be used in the function
        args = [float(arg) for arg in input('Insert the arguments (delimited by spaces): ').split()]

        # Check if passed arguments match with function arguments
        expected_args = func.__code__.co_argcount
        actual_args = len(args)
        if actual_args != expected_args:
            print(f'Invalid number of arguments, expected {expected_args}, found {actual_args}')
            continue
        
        # Call the function with the provided arguments
        print('The result is', func(*args))
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage example:

```
Insert the function name (type "exit" to stop): f
Insert the arguments (delimited by spaces): 10
The result is 100.0
Insert the function name (type "exit" to stop): dist
Insert the arguments (delimited by spaces): 3 4
The result is 5.0
Insert the function name (type "exit" to stop): g
Insert the arguments (delimited by spaces): 1
The result is 2.0
Insert the function name (type "exit" to stop): f
Insert the arguments (delimited by spaces): 1 2
Invalid number of arguments, expected 1, found 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. By using regular expressions you can figure out what the function is by looking at the input string. İf you used any graphics calculater like desmos or geogebra, when you enter a mathematical expression as a string,the calculator  will figure out what to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

To parse math from a string input, you can use regular expressions.
If your question is *how to run a specific function by calling it in a command-line input*, you can store the functions in a separate module and use the *inspect* module to get references to these functions and their names.

```
import some_module
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
    
functions = dict(getmembers(some_module, isfunction))
print("Available functions are: ", *functions.keys())
while True:
    print("Type the name of the function you want to run and press enter.")
    try:
        functions[input()]()
    except KeyError:
        print("No such function found.")


>>> Available functions are:  empty_function1 empty_function2
>>> Type the name of the function you want to run and press enter.
>>> Whatever
>>> No such function found.
>>> Type the name of the function you want to run and press enter.
>>> empty_function2
>>> Hello from the function 2!
```